# dynamic diameter in bubble chart in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269 the diameter = 960.how to dynamic this diameter according to my nodes size.want to change the size increase and decrease as the number of nodes increase and decrease.I tried different approaches but cant get.

Comment: unclear what you ask

Comment: I wan to change my diameter size according to the number of nodes,What I am doing now is,I am calculating the node from my json,suppose I have 20 nodes.i am multiplying this 20 with 10(want to equal size of node) ,so my size = 200 for 20 nodes correct!, now If my json has 30 nodes then my size will be 30 * 10 =300 which is 300 correct.but the the radius node for the 20 is different from the 30 nodes. here I cant understand why my radius increase as the number of nodes increase.the radius should be fix for all nodes,if it has 20 or 30 or what ever.(mean I want fix radius of a single node )

Comment: @user1872177 can you show an example of how the size of the nodes change depending on your number of nodes? like host it on jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: please look at this https://jsfiddle.net/5xLjy1ra/1/ here my radius is r="31.17" fo 20 nodes.if you change the number of nodes to 14 nodes then r=29.82 for and for 9 nodes and r = 21.95 for 9 nodes.plz let me know if you have still confusion

Comment: as the nodes increase the radius of individual node increase. for 9 nodes r =21.95, for 14 nodes r = 29.82 and for 20 nodes r = 31.17.

Comment: you understand my point or not?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the entire visualization's width and height to dynamically changed based on the number/size of the nodes.

This is not possible with the `d3.layout.pack()`. However, you might want to know that the radius of each node is actually dynamically calculated based on the `size` of the layout:

> ## pack.radius([radius])
>
> If radius is specified, sets the radius function for computing the radius of each node. If radius is null, as it is by default, the radius is determined automatically from the node value, scaled to fit the layout size. If radius is not specified, returns the current radius function, which defaults to null. The radius can also be specified as a constant number for uniform circle size.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#radius

Hence, by default without specifying the `# pack.radius([radius])`, given a fixed-size layout, the nodes will always fit the layout.

Comment: thank you so much,you understand my point.I have fixed size for each node.but the problem is as I increase the number of nodes the radius of node increase. i am counting my nodes and then multiplying it with a constant number like 10.like for 20 nodes my diameter size is 200 and for 30 nodes my diameter size is 300.but the radius of a single node in the 20 nodes is less then the radius of a single node in 30 nodes.mean as I increase the number of nodes the radius of each node is increase which is my problem.i want same size of radius